# Starting the Manipulation Pipeline: self_filter.yaml

Tags: ros, pr2-tabletop-manipulation-apps

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**ROS Electric**
**Ubuntu Natty Narwhal**

---

Hello everybody,

I'm following the tutorial Starting the Manipulation Pipeline".
When I run `roslaunch pr2_tabletop_manipulation_launch pr2_tabletop_manipulation.launch` I have the following error message:

`error loading <rosparam> tag:<br> file does not exist [/opt/ros/electric/stacks/pr2_arm_navigation/pr2_arm_navigation_perception/config/self_filter.yaml]<br> XML is <rosparam command="load" file="$(find pr2_arm_navigation_perception)/config/self_filter.yaml"/>`

Indeed `self_filter.yaml` does not exist in the directory.

Could someone please point me in the right direction here?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11967/starting-the-manipulation-pipeline:-self_filter.yaml/) by [Dr Z](https://answers.ros.org/users/1311/dr-z/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-11-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Change the file name to one of these (as per your requirement): old_self_filter.yaml ; self_filter_left.yaml ; self_filter_right.yaml. Because of frequent updates file name have been changed and tutorials that you are following may be old. If you don't have any of these files then get a fresh copy of pr2_arm_navigation.

---

Originally posted by [VN](https://answers.ros.org/users/841/vn/) with karma: 373 on 2011-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dr Z](https://answers.ros.org/users/1311/dr-z/) on 2011-11-21**:
Thanks VN, renaming one of these files worked for me.

**Comment by [Dr Z](https://answers.ros.org/users/1311/dr-z/) on 2011-11-19**:
Thanks, I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I saw this problem this afternoon too.  However, I just apt-updated ROS and it is fixed now.  You need to update pr2_object_manipulation_launch, note, not pr2_arm_navigation.  The laser+stereo-perception.launch file was calling self_filter.yaml which no longer exists.  In the newer version, it correctly calls self_filter_left/right.yaml.

---

Originally posted by [jbarry](https://answers.ros.org/users/486/jbarry/) with karma: 280 on 2011-11-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dr Z](https://answers.ros.org/users/1311/dr-z/) on 2011-11-20**:
Thank you for your answer. I couldn't find pr2_object_manipulation_launch in the Electric repository. I followed VN comments and it worked for me.